# Error while installing Sharp in Azure-Function

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, sharp

I have an azure function that triggers via blob storage and does some operations on the images with the help of sharp library. I tested the code locally and it is working fine but when deployed to Azure it gives the following error.

> Error: Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../../vendor/lib/libvips-cpp.so.42: file too short - Remove the "node_modules/sharp" directory then run "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose" and look for errors - Consult the installation documentation at https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install - Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues ' Stack: Error: Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../../vendor/lib/libvips-cpp.so.42: file too short - Remove the "node_modules/sharp" directory then run "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose" and look for errors - Consult the installation documentation at https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install - Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues at Object. (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:34:9) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32) at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18) at Object. (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js:3:15) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)

after googling I found this.

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1122

I am not sure if it was Azure issue or Sharp issue.

Comment: Have you tried to delete your `node_modules` folder and then do `npm install`?

Comment: yes I tried but same issue.

Comment: Which  does the system of Azure function? Windows or LInux?

Comment: I am using Linux is this issue will solve if I use docker.